# How would I create a method that accepts the raw input instead of using data post-calculation?

Tags: java, methods, time, duration

I am trying to write a program that shows the hour/min/sec and elapsed time given a specific hour/min/sec input as well as a long sec input. So far, I have it showing the correct hour, minute, and second. However, the elapsed time is using the data after the calculations have completed.

For example, if I input hours/mins/sec as 331 34 674, it returns 19 hours 45 minutes 14 seconds, as it is supposed to. (I am not showing days, so I'm just taking hr % 24. However, when I asked for the elapsed time in seconds, it returns 71114 (equal to 19 hours 45 minutes 14 seconds) instead of the expected 1194314 (331 hours 45 minutes 14 seconds). Why? How do I fix? I have attached the code below.

```
package CHTime;


import java.util.Scanner;
public class CHTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Declare variables
        Scanner chIn = new Scanner(System.in);
                
        // Prompt user for input time1
        System.out.println("Enter time1 (hour minute second): ");
        int chHr = chIn.nextInt();
        int chMin = chIn.nextInt();
        int chSec = chIn.nextInt();
        CHTime chTime1 = new CHTime(chHr, chMin, chSec);
        
        // Display Results
        System.out.println(chTime1.toString());
        
        // Display elapsed time in time1
        System.out.println("Elapsed seconds in time1: " + chTime1.getSeconds());
        
        
        // Prompt user for elapsed time
        System.out.println("Enter time2 (elapsed time): ");
        CHTime chTime2 = new CHTime(chIn.nextLong());
        
        // Display results
        System.out.println(chTime2.toString());
        
        // Display elapsed time in time 2
        System.out.println("Elapsed seconds in time2: " + chTime2.getSeconds());
    }

}
```

```
package CHTime;

public class CHTime implements Comparable<CHTime>
{
    // Data field for elapsed time since midnight Jan 1, 1970
    private long chUnix = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
    
    // Data fields for hour, min, and sec
    private int chHr;
    private int chMin;
    private int chSec;
        
    
    // Constructor with specified hour, min, and sec to create a time
    public CHTime(int chHr, int chMin, int chSec)
    {
        this.chSec = chSec % 60;
        this.chHr = chHr % 24;
        this.chMin = (chMin + chSec / 60) % 60;
    }
    
    // Constructor with specified time since Unix
    public CHTime(long chElapsedTime)
    {
        this.chSec = (int)(chElapsedTime) % 60;
        chHr = (int)(chElapsedTime / 60);
        this.chMin = chHr % 60;
        this.chHr = (chHr / 60) % 24;
    }
    
    // Create method that returns the hour in range 0-23
    public int getHour()
    {
        return chHr;
    }
    
    // Create method that returns the minute in range 0 - 59
    public int getMinute()
    {
        return chMin;
    }
    
    // Create method that returns the second in range 0 - 59
    public int getSecond()
    {
        return chSec;
    }
    
    // Create method that returns the elapsed total seconds
    public long getSeconds()
    {
        return (chHr * 3600) + (chMin * 60) + chSec;
    }
    
    @Override // Create a method that returns a string showing time
    public String toString()
    {
        return chHr + " hours " + chMin + " minutes " + chSec + " seconds";
    }
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `Duration`class instead of your own `CHTime` class? Don’t reinvent the wheel if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You are running the function getSeconds() after you calculate chHr, chMin, and chSec. so they are 19, 45, and 14 respectively, and not 331, 34, and 674.

my suggestion:

You could either calculate the seconds in the constructor and keep it as a parameter before calculating the others.

Or keep the original values given in the constructor and use them in the getSeconds function.

Answer (score 0):

look at the difference of the expected and the received value for second: the difference between 71114 (received) and 1194314 (expected) is exectly the 13 days, that you modulo'ed away.

Your code is absolutely OK, its your expectation that is wrong: days are stripped, so you won't get them back magically :-)

And please quit your habit of naming function params and member variables identically and use "this" to tell between them. You will not get a happy live this way. make your params clearly distinguishable by e.g. naming them e.g. "p_chMin".
Doing it "your way" caries the risk to accidentally forget one the many this'es and writing your data into a param (volatile) instead of the class member (persistent).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store initial value of epoch seconds hours/minutes/seconds i suggest convert it to single Instant value and just call respective methods on it.

```
public class CHTime implements Comparable<CHTime> {
        private final Instant chInstant;
    
        public CHTime(int chHr, int chMin, int chSec) {
            this.chInstant = Instant.ofEpochSecond((chHr * 3600) + (chMin * 60) + chSec);
        }
    
        public CHTime(long chElapsedTime) {
            this.chInstant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(chElapsedTime);
        }
    
        public int getHour() {
            int hours = chInstant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getHour() - 1;
            return hours < 0 ? 23 : hours;
        }
    
        public int getMinute() {
            return chInstant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute();
        }
    
        public int getSecond() {
            return chInstant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getSecond();
        }
    
        public long getSeconds() {
            return chInstant.getEpochSecond();
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getHour() + " hours " + getMinute() + " minutes " + getSeconds() + " seconds";
        }
    }
```

Also this constructor:

```
public CHTime(int chHr, int chMin, int chSec)
    {
        this.chSec = chSec % 60;
        this.chHr = chHr % 24;
        this.chMin = (chMin + chSec / 60) % 60;
    }
```

Adds minutes from seconds, but doesn't do same for hours, which is inconsistent. Using Instant would solve this problem.

### Edit 1

ZonedDateTime getHour() method for 00:00:00-00:59:59 will return 1, and for 23:00:00-23:59:59 will return 0. I edited my answer to take that into consideration.

Comment: Ok, I think this has me on the right track, however, my hour return is off by 5 hours.

331 34 674 returns 14 hours 45 minutes 14 seconds instead of 19 hours

93889345 returns 11 hours 22 minutes 25 seconds instead of 16 hours

Comment: Are you sure your input is correct? I just run it with 331 34 674 and it returned 19:45:14 (after change i mention in first edit)